# How to copy files from usb to ubuntu server 12.04

Tags: 12.04

I have a Ubuntu server 12.04. And I want to copy the files of my website files to /var/www folder on Ubuntu server system . I don't know how to do it.. Please!!!!

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to give my user permission to add/edit files on local apache server?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/233046/how-to-give-my-user-permission-to-add-edit-files-on-local-apache-server)

Answer (score 1):

you have to use [cp](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html) with sudo since /var/www have  permissions:

```
sudo cp /media/your-usb/whatever /var/www/
```

For example lets say your usb is mounted under /media/usb and you want to copy file named file.txt to /var/www

```
sudo cp /media/usb/file.txt /var/www/
```

Take a look for these:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/FilePermissions

Comment: It works!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: @CrazyCoder So accept the answer. take a look http://www.askubuntu.com/tour